# Best event to track the DML operations being performed on Server along with the hostname performing those operations?

Tags: sql-server-2012, extended-events

Currently I'm using the XE event `sql_statement_completed` to track the DML statements that are being executed and the hostname that is performing the same. However this event gets fired for each and every SQL statement, and has to be short-circuited later on, by setting the predicate to filter out statements that are `NOT LIKE 'INSERT%'`, `NOT LIKE 'UPDATE%'` and `NOT LIKE 'DELETE%'`.
The event `degree_of_parallelism` gets fired only for the DML statements, however it `does not provide` the `statement`, `only provides` the `sql_text`. Setting `collect_statement = (1)` for `degree_of_parallelism` returns an error stating the "collect_statement" attribute does not exist for degree_of_parallelism. Is there a way around such that the event gets fired only for DML statements i.e. `INSERT`,`UPDATE` and `DELETE`, and the statement that fired the event is provided too?

Below is the `sql_statement_completed` event script that I have to use that is not very optimal:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [XE_Demo] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
   ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_connection_id,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_instance_name,sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.transaction_id,sqlserver.username)
WHERE ([SQLSERVER].[IS_SYSTEM]=(0) AND (([STATEMENT] like 'INSERT%' OR [STATEMENT] like 'UPDATE%' OR [STATEMENT] like 'DELETE%')) 
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'XE_Demo.xel',max_file_size=(102400),max_rollover_files=(10000),metadatafile=N'C:\XE_Demo.xem')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=1048576 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=NO_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=5 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
```

PS. I do know that sql_text also provides the statement that fired the event, however this sql_text is nothing but the `DBCC input buffer` and in case your statement consists of the keyword 'password' anywhere, your buffer would be flushed and you won't get access to the statement anymore.